# Is that possible to have a single DbContext, with migration files being split in different assemblies?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I've built a system which have a Core solution and a Custom solution for each of our clients.
The Core has it own dbcontext, and each Customs have their own dbcontext for client specific tables.
Custom solution is referencing Core solution dlls.
Custom dlls are being dynamically loaded by the Core solution in a plugin architecture.
Since Core and Custom have their own dbcontext, each one have their own migration files.

All is working pretty well except for one thing, i cannot make a linq query that join a Core table with Custom table. (Ex: joining ProjectCustom with Project in a single query). 
I get the error:

```
The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts.
```

So to allow query joining tables from both Core and Custom,  i'm thinking of going another route where the Core define a base abstract DbContext and the Custom inherits from this dbcontext and add its custom tables. So i have a single dbcontext at run time.

Now to my question, is there any way that i could have migration files in Core, and another set of migration files defined in Custom ?

I've made a working solution where all migrations were maintained in the Custom solution. However i don't like the fact that if i make a manual migration affecting Core tables, i have to manually propagate it to all Custom solutions.

I would like to keep migrations affecting Core tables into that Core solution, and have another set of migrations for customs. All applied to the same dbcontext, which the final implementation reside in the custom solution.

Is that possible ? Is there any way to configure some kind of provider for the migrations files ? So i could first apply migrations defined in Core solution then apply migration from custom, using the same dbcontext.

Comment: Part 1 you will have to inherit your core dbContext into your custom dbContext if you want to be able to link across them.

Comment: Part 2 once you have your custom dbContext inheriting from core you would have to create migrations from the custom and not core.

Comment: @JasonH I explained how I tried this solution and how I didn't like the fact that if i make a manual migration affecting Core tables(ie: things code first will not generate migration for ex: stored proc, full text search, ...), i have to manually duplicate it to all Custom solutions. I would like to isolate Core migrations and re-use them across all customs.

Comment: I do not think what you are looking for is possible.

Comment: I suggest you go for an easier route. Modify your DbContext to receive by constructor another DbContext (the custom) and inspect the Entities and ComplexType associated with it, include the registered types in the Core context and use Set<T>() generic to retrieve the custom collections.

Comment: This will only be possible is Custom and Core are pointing to the same Db join between diff database is possible neither.

Comment: @Miguel Interesting, you've implemented this idea and is working good ? So this means that client code can join dbContextCore.CoreTable and dbContextCore.CustomTable (CustomTable being a property that returns a DbSet from the injected custom dbcontext) together in a single linq query ?

Comment: I haven't implemented this yet because I don't need it so far, but what I'm suggesting you is the same that you configure for the DbContext manually. In this case, instead of registering all the types in code you will be registering from an external DbContext (maybe you need some reflection to get there). I don't see any problem with this approach.

Comment: @GuillaumeMorin check the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Source Code](https://github.com/mabreuortega/stackoverflow/tree/master/EntityFramework.CrossJoin)

Let's start by creating an interface for the Context's configuration

```
public interface IDbContextRegistry
{
    void Configure(DbModelBuilder builder);
}
```

In my case, the implementation lives in the each individual Context but implementing this in a diff class will be nice.

```
public class ContextA : DbContext, IDbContextRegistry
{
    static ContextA()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ContextA, ConfigurationA>());
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        Configure(modelBuilder);
    }

    public void Configure(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ModelA>();
    }
}
internal sealed class ConfigurationA : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ContextA>
{
    public ConfigurationA()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(ContextA context)
    {
    }
}

public class ModelA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
public class ContextB : DbContext, IDbContextRegistry
{
    static ContextB()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ContextB, ConfigurationB>());
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        Configure(modelBuilder);
    }

    public void Configure(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ModelB>();
    }
}
internal sealed class ConfigurationB : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ContextB>
{
    public ConfigurationB()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(ContextB context)
    {
    }
}

public class ModelB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }
}
```

Later in your main app create a Context that will register all the individual types.

```
public class ContextJoin : DbContext
{
    private readonly List<IDbContextRegistry> _registry = new List<IDbContextRegistry>();

    // Constructor to allow automatic DI injection for most modern containers
    public ContextJoin(IEnumerable<IDbContextRegistry> registry)
    {
        _registry.AddRange(registry);
    }

    public ContextJoin(params IDbContextRegistry[] registry) : this(_registry.AsEnumerable())
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        foreach (var entry in _registry)
        {
            entry.Configure(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

and voila, every entity is living in the ContextJoin and ready to use. 
Example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ContextA ctxA = new ContextA();
        ctxA.Set<ModelA>().Add(new ModelA());
        ctxA.SaveChanges();

        ContextB ctxB = new ContextB();
        ctxB.Set<ModelB>().Add(new ModelB());
        ctxB.SaveChanges();

        ContextJoin ctxJoin = new ContextJoin(ctxA, ctxB);
        ctxJoin.Set<ModelB>().Add(new ModelB());
        ctxJoin.Set<ModelA>().Add(new ModelA());
        ctxJoin.SaveChanges();

        var crossQuery = ctxJoin.Set<ModelA>().Join(
            ctxJoin.Set<ModelB>(), t => t.Id, t => t.Id, (a, b) => new
            {
                a.Name,
                b.Date
            }).ToList();
        crossQuery.ForEach(t => Console.WriteLine($"Name: {t.Name}, Date: {t.Date}"));
    }
}
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Awesome ! But there is something going on, when I issue a simple ctxJoin.Set<ModelA>().ToList(), all entries are returned but all properties are null. Using ctxA.Set<ModelA>().ToList() works ok.

Comment: Just to be clear, I did edit your code to set some value in Name and Date properties prior to save, and all values are saved to database. But when I get a list using ctxJoin, Name and Date are null.

Comment: Forget that, I just realized you had included a github solution. All is working well in yours. So I probably did stupid things in my implementation. Thank you very much sir, I'll continue my tests but this seems like a great solution.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: How would you implement this when using Dependency Injection?

Comment: @turbophi register each the individual context to your DI Container. I added a new constructor for ContextJoin that depends on IEnumerable<IDbContextRegistry> this will automatically resolve all the registered IDbContextRegistry and pass it to your ContextJoin instance.