# Is it possible to inject a dependency into a DbContext when using AddDbContext?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I'm trying to implement [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43483222/1884857) using Dependency Injection.

All my DbContexts are registered using *EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.AddDbContext*. However I don't know how to add dependencies that would be passed to the constructor (which can then be registered as member variables so thatthey can be accessed when *Db.Context.OnModelCreating* is called).

```
public static IServiceCollection AddCustomDbContexts(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<FirstContext>(options => options.UseMySql("foobar");
    services.AddDbContext<SecondContext>(options => options.UseMySql("foobar"); // HOW TO PASS FirstContext?
    return services;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking. You want to use FirstContext from SecondContext? Did you try declaring a parameter for your SecondContext's constructor so that it accepts a FirstContext?

Comment: Can you show an example of  `I don't know how to add dependencies that would be passed to the constructor`?  It's not that clear to me what you're asking for. Do you mean pass first context in the AddCustomDbContext constructor?

Comment: Yes @mason. Did not think about the easiest solution... Thanks... (feeling ashamed).